# Linux server halting every few days

Tags: linux

Our Linux Server keeps getting the following message every few days. Where would I go to track down this issue?

> Broadcast message from root (Mon Mar 
>   1 20:13:57 2010):
>
> The system is going down for system
>   halt NOW!

Edit:
/var/log/messages looks like this

> Mar  1 18:10:05 CFMC2
>   sshd(pam_unix)[3326]: session closed
>   for user alberte
>
> Mar  1 20:13:57 CFMC2 shutdown:
>   shutting down for system halt
>
> Mar  1 20:13:57 CFMC2 init: Switching
>   to runlevel: 0
>
> Mar  1 20:13:57 CFMC2 gconfd
>   (cfmc-5252): Received signal 15,
>   shutting down cleanly
>
> Mar  1 20:13:57 CFMC2 gconfd
>   (cfmc-5252): Exiting

I also just foound this after running the command 'last'

> reboot   system boot  2.6.9-67.0.1.ELs Mon Mar  1 20:41          (15:35)

Thanks,
Digital Ninja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last time I saw this it turned out to be a bad motherboard sensor.  The sensor was convinced the server was overheating and the OS would just shut down.

Check your BIOS or built-in management for hardware event logs that might describe what is happening.

Comment: Could also be a flaky power switch - I had a server that would power itself down randomly and it turned out to be a power switch that would intermittently close and send the "ACPI power off" signal.  Stuff like this usually leaves a helpful log message (at least on FreeBSD, I think Linux does too)

Answer (score 2):

Dude, someone has put `shutdown -h now` into `crontab`.

Check `/var/log/cron`

Comment: Check /etc/cron* & crontab -l

Comment: I checked my cron and /var/log/cron and I don't see anything strange. Nothing is even remotely scheduled to happen the same time the server shuts down. Almost always at 7:30 - 8:30 pm cst.

Comment: Can you post some entries from `/var/log/messages` ? 

Also, is there a keyboard on this machine? Could someone be hitting `CTL-ATL-DELETE`, or possibly something else triggering the reboot ?

Comment: If it's *always* at the same time +/- a few minutes or so it's something scheduled (cron, something remote, a cleaning lady who bumps the power switch); otherwise see David Mackintosh's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a UPS attached to the machine? Are you sure it's not telling the machine to shut down because it thinks it's dying?

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

- Who has access to this box?  Check to see who logged on during those times and check the shell history files.
- Have you checked out the log files for anything strange?
- What do you have running on this box?  Anything particular happening when this occurs?
- Any time similarities to when this happens?